# How to compare and validate form values before sending in Django Admin?

Tags: python, sql, django, validation, admin

In my admin panel, users can edit a dropdown to set values for one or more lines before saving the changes. When 2 or more lines are edited at once, I would like to check if the values set by the user are coherent.
 [Here is an example.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5UIEQ.png)

These two rows should not have 2 different values.

I have tried overriding the clean() methods in the model but I need to validate the data before this is triggered, preferably right after the form is sent. Is this possible? Official Django Documentation mostly describes data validation form in the model, but this would not allow me to compare rows between them.

Here is my Alarm model:

```
import uuid

from django.db import models

from backoffice.models.AlarmDataStatus import AlarmDataStatus
from backoffice.models.Device import Device
from backoffice.models.SigfoxDevice import SigfoxDevice
from backoffice.models.Site import Site
from backoffice.utils.util import get_sensor_html_field


class Alarm(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    site = models.ForeignKey(Site, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    sigfox_device = models.ForeignKey(SigfoxDevice, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    device = models.ForeignKey(Device, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    date = models.DateTimeField()
    send_client_email = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    value = models.FloatField()
    threshold = models.FloatField(null=True)
    reference = models.FloatField(null=True)
    message = models.TextField(max_length=500)
    value_status = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=AlarmDataStatus.choices, default=AlarmDataStatus.PENDING)
    comment = models.TextField(max_length=500, null=True, blank=True)

    def to_dict(self):
        return {
            'time': int(self.date.timestamp()),
            'site_id': str(self.site.id),
            'device': str(self.sigfox_device.id),
            'alarm_type': self.type,
            'value': self.value,
            'message': self.message,
            'send_client_email': self.send_client_email
        }

    def current_sensor(self):
        if self.device is None:
            return '-'
        return get_sensor_html_field(self.device.id, self.device.name())
```

And here is my AlarmAdmin code:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.admin import SimpleListFilter

from backoffice.models import Alarm
from backoffice.models.AlarmDataStatus import AlarmDataStatus
from backoffice.utils.util import is_prod
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _


class IsPendingFilter(SimpleListFilter):
    title = _('Status')

    parameter_name = 'status'

    def lookups(self, request, model_admin):
        return (
            (None, _('PENDING')),
            ('PUBLISHED', _('PUBLISHED')),
            ('REFUSED', _('REFUSED')),
            ('TO DISCUSS', _('TO DISCUSS')),
            ('all', _('All')),
        )

    def choices(self, cl):
        for lookup, title in self.lookup_choices:
            yield {
                'selected': self.value() == lookup,
                'query_string': cl.get_query_string({
                    self.parameter_name: lookup,
                }, []),
                'display': title,
            }

    def queryset(self, request, queryset):
        if self.value() in ('PUBLISHED', 'REFUSED', 'TO DISCUSS'):
            return queryset.filter(value_status=self.value())
        elif self.value() == None:
            return queryset.filter(value_status='PENDING')
        else:
            return queryset

@admin.register(Alarm)
class AlarmAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['type', 'site', 'current_sensor', 'sigfox_device', 'date', 'value', 'threshold', 'send_client_email', 'value_status']
    ordering = ['-date']
    list_editable = ("send_client_email", "value_status")
    list_filter = [(IsPendingFilter), 'type', ('site', admin.RelatedOnlyFieldListFilter)]

    def get_fieldsets(self, request, obj=None):
        self.fieldsets = [
            (None, {'fields': ['type', 'site', 'sigfox_device', 'date', 'value', 'threshold', 'message', 'value_status', 'send_client_email', 'comment']})
        ]
        return super(AlarmAdmin, self).get_fieldsets(request, obj)

    def get_readonly_fields(self, request, obj=None):
        if obj:
            return ['type', 'site', 'sigfox_device', 'date', 'value', 'threshold', 'message']
        return []

    def has_add_permission(self, request):
        return False

    def has_delete_permission(self, request, obj=None):
        return not is_prod()
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you not use a custom ModelForm for making this validation?
Example one the official documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#adding-custom-validation-to-the-admin